# Instead of Maven Repo, usage of .m2 directory

Tags: java, maven

I have worked in the offline development environment.
First, I downloaded dependencies from the maven repository via the maven central repository. After, moving the .m2 folder to the offline development environment is it possible to work without a maven repository

Comment: Maven has a command line option: `-o` or `--offline` for working offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html.

You may pass the path to a local repo via `-Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/repo`. If you use it regularly you should probably add an alias for `mvn`.

Or you add `<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>` to your build file.

Maven should look in the local repo first anyway (default is `~/.m2/repository`). So if you have all the required dependencies in the required version there maven should not make any requests to the outside wordl. But that's just a guess.